# In OpenGl do VBOs have to contain data with the same vertex layout?

Tags: opengl, vbo

I used to have many VBOs, but I now combined them into one and just index into it depending on what I draw. The issue is that when I load vertices into a VBO and keep a record of how many bytes into the buffer it is it doesn't match with the argument in glDrawArrays, whose offset argument is "first", not offset in bytes. If all the vertices in the VBO are the same layout, am I supposed to do a division? For example, sizeof(Vertex) == 12 and it's placed in VBO at byte offset 48, to draw four vertices do I need to do glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 48 / sizeof(Vertex), 4) ???

What if it's a big buffer that contains two different types of vertex with a different layout? As buffer areas are freed to make space for other ones and they're moved around or resized how is this supposed to be done?

To set up the vertices I call glVertexAttribPointer and glEnableVertexArray four or five times, I was trying to avoid calling these for each draw call.

Answer (score 1):

If the format of vertices have changed, then this means that (using the old API), you would have to have have made some number of `glVertexAttribPointer` calls (possibly as part of a new VAO you're going to bind) in order to change the format of the vertex data. Either way, calling this function gives you the opportunity to change the byte offset from which each attribute starts in the buffer.

So if your buffer contains 256 bytes of data in layout 1, followed by 256 bytes of data in layout 2, then the "pointer" you provide as the byte offset when setting up layout 2 should be offset by 256: the starting offset for the new vertex data.

That way, your `glDrawArrays` function would take an index of 0 for both meshes, since any offsetting is part of the vertex format.

And FYI yes, the "first" parameter to `glDrawArrays` is an index, not a byte offset.

> I was trying to avoid calling these for each draw call.

If you want to avoid that, then you need to sort your models by vertex format, so that you render all models for one format, then models using a different one. Layout changes aren't cheap, so if performance is supposed to matter, pick a small pool of vertex formats and make your meshes conform to them.

Comment: Say you have a buffer in a VBO and you know what offset it is in bytes, and provided you know the vertex layout, doing a division is much better than resetting the glVertexAttrib pointers, isn't it? I mean division to go from byte offset to vertex index "first"

Comment: @Zebrafish: Your question specifically asks about having two different "layouts". By definition, that means you *have to* call `glVertexAttribPointer` again or bind a new VAO.